# Spring dynamic parameter injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to get my head around the autowiring concept, but I am facing the problem of a bean with a dependency that needs an int in the constructor but I dunno how to provide it dynamically without putting a static value in the config.

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class BootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(BootDemoApplication.class, args);
        Account account = applicationContext.getBean(Account.class, 231);
    }
}
```

Bean:

```
@Component
public class Account {

    @Autowired
    Salary salary;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(salary.getSalary());
    }

}
```

Dependency:

```
@Component
public class Salary {

    private int salary;

    public Salary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in io.cptpackage.springboot.bootdemo.account.Salary required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.
```

Comment: There is no configuration that applies to a constructor for Salary receiving an int parameter. Either you create a default constructor in Salary without parameters or you add a configuration to it with an int parameter. Spring Boot search for default constructor as default.

Comment: But what if I want the value of that int to be inserted dynamically, like when I create the bean it asks for the value of the salary not looking for it int the configuration file. As I understood the configuration file will have have a fixed value for it, but what if I want a salary for an object to be for example 5 and for another one 8 should I do it through configuration or can I do dynamically through the code? And do I have to use the xml configuration or annotations?

Comment: That's not how beans work. Beans are singletons by default. So, every time you ask for a Salary (which should not be a Spring bean in the first place), you'll get the same instance. I have a hard time understanding why you're modelling an Account or a Salary as spring beans. It doesn't make much sense. Typcical Spring beans are REST controllers, services, repositories, which are stateless except for dependencies on other Spring beans.

Comment: In the configuration you will only tell spring that whoever calls it need to pass an INT.

Comment: And @JBNizet is totally right, makes no sense this design unless you want just to test how the beans works.

Comment: @JBNizet It is an example for me to review nothing much, sorry for the inconvenience but I am just a beginner with it. So, in these cases I should use normal POJOs or prototype beans?

Comment: Account and Salary are just stateful classes, and you typically create them, using new, when needed. No need for Spring here.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh okay POJOs then, but can you give me an example where I use the prototype just to get my head around the whole idea of it?

Comment: I can't remember a single time in recent years where I've used prototype beans. Request-scope beans, yes. But prototype beans, never.